# Reuse params in React Router <Redirect />

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I want to redirect from `/web/` or `/beta/` to `/web/dashboard` or `/beta/dashboard/`, respectively.

I tried using  as follows ...

`<Redirect exact from="/:platform(web|beta)" to="/:platform/dashboard" />`

The problem is that when I got to `www.abc.com/beta` it simply redirects me to `www.abc.com/undefined/dashboard` instead of replacing the `:platform` with `beta`.

For Reference I'm using the following version: `"react-router-dom": "^4.2.2"`

Answer (score 1):

One solution that I found works is instead of relying on the params, you can access the `location.pathname` prop.

```
<Redirect exact from="/:platform(web|beta)/" to={`${this.props.location.pathname}/dashboard`}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get those params from the props

for the latest version of react router it's

`this.props.match.params.platform`

[Docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/match)

Comment: depends where you are using the redirect, match is available from the Route component

Comment: It is being used outside of the `<Route/>` component. It's inside a `<Switch>` in `<App />`

Comment: your Redirect syntax actually works. [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/69kv6o5m3)

Comment: You're right but I have no clue why it didn't work for me in my code... hmm.